# Manually ending or canceling touch phase in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, touch, coronasdk

Is it possible to manually cancel or end the touch phase on an object? I basically want to make it impossible for the user to drag the object unless they take there finger off the screen and start to drag it again. Is this possible?

Comment: you can do it in a simple way by adding flag.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry, about my questions. I'm quite a noob.

Answer (score 2):

```
local isDragAllowed = 0  -- create a flag or a variable

local bg = display.newRect(0,0,display.contentWidth,display.contentHeight) -- background

local myObject = display.newImageRect("Icon.png", 50, 50); -- your object
myObject.x = 160
myObject.y = 240

local function touchHandler(event)
    if(event.phase=="began")then
        isDragAllowed = 1
    elseif(event.phase=="moved" and isDragAllowed==1)then
        -- object will be moved only if the flag is true or 1
        myObject.x = event.x
        myObject.y = event.y
    else
        isDragAllowed = 0 -- resetting the flag on touch end
    end
    return true;
end
myObject:addEventListener("touch",touchHandler)

local function bgTouchHandler(event)
    print(event.phase)
    isDragAllowed = 0 -- resetting the flag if drag/touch happens on background
    return true;
end
bg:addEventListener("touch",bgTouchHandler)
```